# How many stores can I create in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, multistore, multi-website

I want to create 2 websites and 2 stores and more than 200 store views, so I want to know if Magento 2 can support so much store views? And after adding all the products, will the performance be the same for all the store views?

Answer (score 3):

**When we talk about code level of Magento 2 - There is no code limit for the creating  of website , stores and store views.**

> **you can create website , store and store views as many as you want**
>   **there is no limit at all on code level.**

But when we talk about performance, yes it will affect on performance when we have huge amount of catalog and multiple store , store views and websites so its totally depends on your hosting environment and server efficiency.

**When this type of complex architecture of magento 2 - you needed very strong hosting environment for speed and performance point of view.**

Comment: what will happen 6k stores if i need, and i have only 20 products.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned earlier there are no code limitation in this area, Although there are some issues that may happen:

- **Tables Locking**
- **Indexation Issues**
- **Concurrent Admin Users Operations**
- **Cache Building and Invalidation Issues** (within deployment process and as standard operating flows)
- **Effective SKU Count**

Of course it all depends on hardware setup and supporting solutions like:

- **Redis**
- **Varnish**
- **CDN Type Solution(s)**
- **Database Sharding/Split** (Magento Commerce only)